# Проверка на исполнение в дизайнтайме

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.

Думаю, ни для кого не секрет, что свинг исполняет код в дизайнтайме, чтобы корректно отображать окно в конструкторе.

Задача: писать проект так, чтобы максимально легко можно было компилировать как десктопное приложение, так и апплет.

Сейчас я делаю проверку на `if (this instanceof JFrame){`.

Всё отлично, для резных компиляций просто заменяю базовый класс окна с JFrame на JApplet.

Проблема в неудбности проектирования при этом - в дизайнтайме плагин эклипса считает, что мой класс - это не наследник фрейма.

Подскажите, как можно организать условие, при котором свинг плагин будет корректно распознавать, что на данный момент мой класс именно наследник JFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант: `new JFrame().add(new JApplet())` - апплет как и другие GUI элементы можно размещать внутри JFrame.

Comment: Перечитайте вопрос пожалуйста. Я не спрашиваю как запустить, апплет принимает компонеты, я спрашиваю как внутри кода понять, что он исполняется из дизайнтайма, во время парсинга свингом. Кстати, апплет на то и апплет, что только он запускается с хтмл страницы, фрейм не запустить так, ваш пример неработоспособен. Минус.

Comment: я не предлагал запускать фрейм в браузере. я предложил все контролы запихнуть в апплет. в случае если нужно запустить его как обычное приложение создаете пустую форму (jframe) и добавляете на нее единственный элемент - ваш апплет

Comment: Я ещё раз говрю - я знаю, как запихнуть контролы в апплет. Делать это просто - есть класс, расширяющий JFrame, меняю расширения на JApplet - получаю компиляцию для сайта.

Мне нужно внутри кода узнать, код исполяется внутри эклипса (дизайнтайм), или при исполнении приложения (или апплета) - рантайм.

Comment: вы не в ту степь копаете, вместо решения этой проблемы:

>> Мне нужно внутри кода узнать, код исполяется внутри эклипса (дизайнтайм), или при исполнении приложения (или апплета) - рантайм.

надо решать эту:

>> эклипса считает, что мой класс - это не наследник фрейма.

Comment: Ответ не найден, но вопрос закрываю (дабы порядок в профиле)...